# How to Access a property which is assigend in codebehind in the View Model in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mediator

I am currently implementing a application using WPF MVVM pattern. There I got into a problem where I am assigning some property(IsClickedYes to true) in codebehind(Let's say Author.xaml.cs), in a mediator method , then when mediator returns to the particular view model(AuthorViewModel.cs) I need to access the IsClickedYes Property which is in Author.xaml.cs from AuthhorViewModel.cs . How Can I achieve this?

Author.cs

```
public class Author
{
    private bool _isClickedYes;

    public bool IsClickedYes
    {
     get { return _isClickedYes; }
     set { _isClickedYes= value; }
    }
    public Author()
    {
    Mediator.Register("SetClickedYesProperty",SetClickedYes);
    }

    private void SetClickedYes(object parameter)
    {
     //Show a Confirm Message Dialog here then if user clicked yes set IsClickedYes property to true

    _isClickedYes=true;
    }
}
```

AuthorViewModel.cs

```
public class AuthorViewModel
{
//this will call the SetClickedYes method in Author.xaml.cs
Mediator.NotifyCollegue("SetClickedYesProperty",null);

//then here I need to access the IsClickedYes Property value of Author.xaml.cs 
if IsClickedYes == true , then do a certain operation otherwise do nothing.


}
```

If I try to create a property in AuthorViwModel and set that property in codebehind, when it returns from mediator it becomes null. So that's Why I created the property in codebehind and assigned the value there, and trying to access it from View Model.
How Can I achieve this, Is there any other way I can achieve this?Please any one guide me if there's any other more good method to achieve this ? Any advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: I wonder why don't you bind? Move IsClickedYes property to the ViewModel after then bind with special control and you will get everything you to want.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that the IsClickedYes property should be part of your viewmodel.  If you are passing the view model in to the View's constructor then everything gets really easy.  You can set the value in your code behind (still), and your view model will always have a handle on the value.  The control in the view (presumably a check box, but perhaps another kind of toggle?) can then have it's value bound (two way) to the view model property.  For this simple case there isn't really a need to use the mediator at all.

Comment: `IsClicked` is part of the UI logic and doesn't belong to the view model in a MVVM scenario. The view knows the state of its properties and can operate accordingly by invoking commands or methods on the view model. The view model only knows states of the model. The name `IsClicked` could be a bad name or it's just reflecting the state of a button.

Comment: @BionicCode My reading differs from yours I guess.  I am thinking this is a view with a checkbox that ties directly to the viewmodel.  Clicking on the checkbox would essentially be a way to propagate a boolean value back to the data model.  Even sorting and filtering though is handled by the VM (with collectionview or homegrown methods).

Comment: Yes, bitte wer don't know. That's why I said maybe he used a bad name. If IsClicked reflects an enabled filter out should be called IsFilterEnabled. In this case you are right. If it is a view related property to determine the state of a button the name is ok but then it doesn't belong into the view model. I was just saying this. We don't know any details at this point and should make the difference clear as he stressed that he is using MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

MVVM wise to put a property `IsClicked` into the view model is wrong. It is view related data and only view related. You should try to avoid this and it's almost ever avoidable.

When it's about the view to trigger a view model operation then the Command Pattern should come into your mind.

But if `IsClicked` reflects a view model state e.g., `IsDataFilterEnabled` then you can use data binding as suggested by others. But in this case you chose a very bad name for your `Author` property. The name *IsClicked* and a button's state are associative.

**Author.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Author : Window
{
  private bool _isClicked;
  public bool IsClicked
  {
    get { return _isClicked; }
    set { _isClickedYes= value; }
  }

  public Author()
  {
    Mediator.Register("EnableIsClickedProperty", EnableIsClicked);
  }

  private void EnableIsClicked(object parameter)
  {
    _isClicked = dialogResult;

    // Assuming that AuthorViewModel is the DataContext of the Author view
    var viewModel = this.DataContext as AuthorViewModel;
    if (_isClicked && viewModel.DoCertainOperationCommand.CanExecute())
    {
      viewModel.DoCertainOperationCommand.Execute();
    }
  }
}
```

**AuthorViewModel.cs**

```
public class AuthorViewModel
{
  public ICommand DoCertainOperationCommand => new RelayCommand(DoCertainOperation, CanExecuteDoCertainOperation);

  private void DoSomething()
  {
    //this will call the EnableIsClicked method in Author.xaml.cs
    Mediator.NotifyCollegue("EnableIsClickedProperty", null);
  }

  private void DoCertainOperation(object param)
  {
    // As this method is only invoked by the view when Author.IsClicked == true,
    // the view model doesn't need to care about the view's property states.
    // IsClicked is UI logic and belongs solely to the view.
  }

  private bool CanExecuteDoCertainOperation => true;
}
```

For brevity I didn't post the code for the `RelayCommand` here. You either already have your own implementation or you will find dozens in the [web](https://helpyourselfhere.blogspot.com/2015/02/wpf-mvvm-relaycommand-implementation.html).

Alternatively call the view model's API directly (from code-behind).